# Как собрать Jackson'ом дерево из потока?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Простите за столь банальный, наверно, для некоторых вопрос. На сайте jsonschema2pojo.org получил POJO для своего дерева, а что делать дальше? Вот само дерево [JSON дерево](https://money.yandex.ru/api/categories-list). В интернете информации практически нет (на русском во всяком случае), а с английским у меня плохо, целый день с переводчиком и документацией по Jackson ни к чему не привел. Не знаю куда еще обратиться за помощью. Помогите, подалуйста, с кодом или дайте ссылку на хороший пример, если знаете. Интересует правильный парсинг именно дерева, а не отдельного элемента или массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял вам необходимо десериализовать json в объект java. Если так то необходимо создать классы описывающие структуру ваших данных например так:

```
public class Sub{
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<Sub> subs;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public List<Sub> getSubs() {
         return subs;
    }

    public void setSubs(List<Sub> subs) {
        this.subs = subs;
    }
}
```

затем с помощью `jackson` десериализуете полученные данные, например вот так, где `jsonString` это соответственно то что нужно преобразовать:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Sub> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Sub.class));
```

Comment: Мне необходимо десериализовать JSON-дерево в коллекцию объектов "категорий" с информацией о подкатегориях. Предложенный Вами способ, как я понимаю, работает только для конкретного одного JSON-объекта. В любом случае, большое Вам спасибо, что откликнулись. И еще, у меня у класса TypeFactory нет метода collectionType();

Comment: Нет, мой пример конкретно делает то что вам нужно, т.е. на выходе вы получаете List с необходимыми объектами. Чтобы было понятнее удалил MyClass Чтобы нужные классы появились используйте зависимости jackson-core и jackson-databind.

Comment: Изменил в примере depricated метод на свежий `defaultInstance().constructCollectionType()`

Comment: Использовал метод: mCategoryList = mapper.readValue(mData, new TypeReference<List<Category>>() {} );  Добавил в описание категории аннотации  JsonProperty("subs")  JsonManagedReference  private List<Category> mSubs;  и добавил поле для родителя  JsonBackReference  private Category mParent;  все вроде бы работает. Аннотации добавил из другого примера, не подскажете, они обязательны?

Comment: Ваш в вопросе json мой пример парсит без проблем без анотаций

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, благодаря Вам вопрос решен!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте почитать эти русскоязычные ссылки:
[Парсинг JSON. Получаем и разбираем JSON с внешнего ресурса](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/)
[Android. Работа с JSON](http://java-help.ru/android-json/)

Comment: Читал обе статьи. Не совсем то, что мне нужно, но спасибо за желание помочь!